# VueJS: Why parent's data property not updated when custom event emitted on child fires?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In the following code, [codePen demo here](https://codepen.io/appu-uno/pen/rErNWJ)

child component emits a custom event `changedMsg` to parent which changes `msg` data property on the parent component. Not sure, why `changedMsg` does not work. It does not modify `msg` property of parent.

Note: In a single file setup this works, but not in the setup below which is using `template` tag. Not sure, why?

**VueJS**

```
var child = {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['parentMsg'],
   methods: {
     changeParentMsg() {
       console.log(this.parentMsg)
       this.parentMsg = 'Message was changed by CHILD'
       this.$emit('changedMsg', this.parentMsg)
     }
   }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#parent',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello World'
    }
  },
  components: {
    child
  },

  methods: {
      changeMsg() {
        this.msg = 'Changed Own Msg'
      }
  },

})
```

**HTML**

```
  <div>
    <h4>Parent</h4>
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>

  <button @click="changeMsg">Change Own Message</button>
  <br>
    <div class="child">
      <h4>Child</h4>
<child :parentMsg="msg" @changedMsg= "msg = $event"></child>
      </div>
</div>
  </div>


<template id="child">
  <div>
    <button @click="changeParentMsg">Change Parnets msg</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: In a single file setup this works, but not in the setup below which is using template tag. Not sure, why?

This is explained in the docs:

[Event Names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)

> Unlike components and props, event names will never be used as variable or property names in JavaScript, so there’s no reason to use camelCase or PascalCase. Additionally, `v-on` event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s case-insensitivity), so `v-on:myEvent` would become `v-on:myevent` – making myEvent impossible to listen to.
>
> For these reasons, we recommend you **always use kebab-case for event names**.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's not a good practice to make the logic on the listem event directive, i made this way and worked:

```
<child :parentMsg="msg" @changed-msg="msgChanged"></child>
  </div>
</div>
```

on the child tag i changed the @changedMsg to kebab-case so now it's @changed-msg and made it call a function instead of do the logic on the child tag, function called msgChanged, so you need to create it on your methods section:

```
methods: {
  changeMsg() {
    this.msg = 'Changed Own Msg'
  },
  msgChanged(param)  {
    console.log(param)
  }
}
```

hope that helps